# Git deployment to Azure Websites suddenly taking over 30 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying to Azure Websites using a git repository. I've been using it for some months now and pushing my ASP.NET MVC 5 application triggers the deployment, which has consistently only ever been one or two minutes.

Today, it is now taking 20-30 minutes to do a deployment. See the log file below. You can see a few multi-minute gaps for no explicable reason.

```
2015-03-04T20:36:06  Updating branch 'master'.
2015-03-04T20:43:52  Updating submodules.
2015-03-04T20:44:07  Preparing deployment for commit id 'cdd77ccfd7'.
2015-03-04T20:44:39  Generating deployment script.
2015-03-04T20:44:46    Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --aspWAP "D:\home\site\repository\Mitigation.Ebb.Web\Mitigation.Ebb.Web.csproj" --solutionFile "D:\home\site\repository\Mitigation.sln"').
2015-03-04T20:44:56  Running deployment command...
2015-03-04T20:44:57    Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
2015-03-04T20:45:00    Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
2015-03-04T20:45:44    All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2015-03-04T20:46:19      Restoring NuGet packages...
2015-03-04T20:46:21      To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
2015-03-04T20:46:26      All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2015-03-04T20:46:46      Restoring NuGet packages...
2015-03-04T20:46:48      To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
2015-03-04T20:47:14      All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2015-03-04T20:47:32      Restoring NuGet packages...
2015-03-04T20:47:34      To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
2015-03-04T20:47:37      All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2015-03-04T20:47:40      CEA.Web.Infrastructure -> D:\home\site\repository\Mitigation.Ebb.Infrastructure\bin\Release\CEA.Web.Infrastructure.dll
2015-03-04T20:47:46      CEA.Web.Mvc -> D:\home\site\repository\CEA.Web.Mvc\bin\Release\CEA.Web.Mvc.dll
2015-03-04T20:48:08      Restoring NuGet packages...
2015-03-04T20:48:11      To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
2015-03-04T20:48:16      All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
2015-03-04T20:49:46      Mitigation.Ebb -> D:\home\site\repository\Mitigation.Ebb\bin\Release\Mitigation.Ebb.dll
2015-03-04T20:53:09      Mitigation.Ebb.Web -> D:\home\site\repository\Mitigation.Ebb.Web\bin\Mitigation.Ebb.Web.dll
2015-03-04T20:53:22      Transformed Web.config using D:\home\site\repository\Mitigation.Ebb.Web\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2015-03-04T20:53:24      Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2015-03-04T20:53:27      D:\local\Temp\1aaba3b6-a9af-4653-991d-87e104112d61.
2015-03-04T21:02:19    KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\local\Temp\1aaba3b6-a9af-4653-991d-87e104112d61' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
2015-03-04T21:02:21    Copying file: 'Web.config'
2015-03-04T21:02:25    Copying file: 'bin\Mitigation.Ebb.dll'
2015-03-04T21:02:28    Copying file: 'bin\Mitigation.Ebb.Web.dll'
2015-03-04T21:02:31    Copying file: 'Views\Home\Contact.cshtml'
2015-03-04T21:02:35    Copying file: 'Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\StringMultiline.cshtml'
2015-03-04T21:02:38    Copying file: 'Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ContactUs\ReasonForContact.cshtml'
2015-03-04T21:02:42    Finished successfully.
2015-03-04T21:02:51  Deployment successful.
```

The only change that occurred today was I tried adding Application Insights to my app. However, the push with that deployed quickly. I've rolled back that change so Application Insights is no longer in the project, but it is still deploying slowly.

[Azure status page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) reports no issues in West US region where I'm running.

UPDATE: My last deployment ran in just a minute, so it's not consistent.

Comment: Could you share the site name either directly or indirectly (see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)?  we can help investigate.

Comment: crmp-ebb-qa.azurewebsites.net --- FWIW, the last three deploys (yesterday) have gone through quickly.

Comment: There is something definitely very, very wrong with my website. This morning I realized I was running on two instances. One of them worked great, the other not so much. I'm thinking it may be related to IncidentId b5b3cba5-ab33-452d-aea1-239b8ee40231 from 3/3/15. I am going to delete the website entirely and re-create it (luckily I have that operation scripted).